# Oracle - Load local/client file to blob column

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, oracle19c

is there a way to load a file from local/client file system to blob column in a sqlplus/plsql script?

I'm having something like this SQL Developer functionality but scripted. Dialog opens when you click on blob column while viewing the table data.

[image]

Comment: you can do it with SQlcl and some javscript - https://krisrice.io/2015-10-14-sqlcl-blob-loading-from-file/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL statements are executed on the server and not on the client's computer and the server has no access to the local file system to be able to read files you have there.

If you particularly want to do it all from the client then use a shell script (or an equivalent) and:

1. Read 2000 bytes from the file you want to load.
2. Convert the 2000 bytes of binary data to 4000 hexadecimal characters.
3. Repeat until the file is read.
4. While doing that, dynamically create an insert statement:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO table_name (
     blob_column
   ) VALUES (
     EMPTY_BLOB()
     || HEXTORAW('<first 4000 hexadecimal characters>')
     || HEXTORAW('<next 4000 hexadecimal characters>')
     -- ...
     || HEXTORAW('<last 4000 hexadecimal characters>')
   );
   ```
5. Execute that SQL statement in `sqlplus`.

Alternatively, write a small Python/Java/C#/etc. program and load the file using that.

Otherwise, if you want a pure PL/SQL solution, transfer the file to the database server and load the file from there.

---

The SQL Developer functionality that you show an image of in the question will effectively work in a similar way. It will probably:

- `INSERT` an empty blob into the table.
- Read back the handle to that blob.
- Read the file in chunks and stream the chunks back to the database server to append them to that blob using the handle to tell the database where the data is going.

You cannot use exactly the same method as you need to read the file on the client before the script sends the statement to the server and the statement needs to be self-contained - there cannot be any interaction from the client during the running of a single SQL or PL/SQL statement.

Comment: Huh, that's what I'm doing right now. As a background I have some static configuration kept like that. It may change from time to time and I need to reload it then. Neither me, nor version control, nor the code reviewer like changes in some  "magic" hex values in sql files though... Currently I have Python script which generates all these hextoraw's for me. I just wanted to make sure that there's no other way to skip the "Pythonisation" (not every sql dev have to know Python after all) and rely solely on sql. Anyway - thanks for the tip!

Comment: @michelson You don't need to store the SQL statement in version control as the hex values. If you have written a script to convert the file to hex and chunk it into 4k string literals and build the SQL statement from that then check that generation script and the original file into version control and dynamically generate the SQL statement when you need it. The code reviewer can then review the original file and can review the correctness of the generation script and if both those are correct then the generated statement will also be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you can move your file to the server - here is the function that reads file into BLOB returning BLOB which can be used to insert/update BLOB column in the table:

```sql
FUNCTION FILE2BLOB  (mDir       IN  VARCHAR2,
                     mFileName  IN  VARCHAR2) RETURN BLOB
IS
BEGIN
    Declare 
        mBLOB       BLOB := Empty_Blob();
        mBinFile    BFILE := BFILENAME(mDir, mFileName);
    Begin
        DBMS_LOB.OPEN(mBinFile, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);             -- Open BFILE
        DBMS_LOB.CreateTemporary(mBLOB, TRUE, DBMS_LOB.Session);    -- BLOB locator initialization
        DBMS_LOB.OPEN(mBLOB, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);               -- Open BLOB locator for writing
        DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile(mBLOB, mBinFile, DBMS_LOB.getLength(mBinFile));   -- Reading BFILE into BLOB
        DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(mBLOB);              -- Close BLOB locator
        DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(mBinFile);           -- Close BFILE
        RETURN mBLOB;       -- Return BLOB
    End;
END FILE2BLOB;
```

NOTE: you will need a Directory object (mDir parameter) that will target the server file system directory
To write BLOB into table column ...

```sql
Update your_table_name 
    Set your_blob_column = FILE2BLOB('your_directory_obj', 'your_file_name') 
Where your_pk_column = PK_VALUE;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't move the file to the server. Thanks for the tip though!